# setting div to 100% still not working

Tags: css

None of the `div` elements on my page seem to be adjustable to 100% height. I've been trying since last night. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    }
    body, td, th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
/* ~~ this fixed width container surrounds all other divs~~ */
.container {
    width: 965px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
    overflow: hidden; /* this declaration makes the .container understand where the floated columns within ends and contain them */
}
 .sidebar1 {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 min-height: 100%;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 380px;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.content2 {
    float: left;
    width: 380px;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
/* ~~ This grouped selector gives the lists in the .content area space ~~ */
.content ul, .content ol {
    padding: 0 15px 15px 40px; /* this padding mirrors the right padding in the headings and paragraph rule above. Padding was placed on the bottom for space between other elements on the lists and on the left to create the indention. These may be adjusted as you wish. */
}
/* ~~ The footer styles ~~ */
.footer {
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;/* this gives IE6 hasLayout to properly clear */
    clear: both; /* this clear property forces the .container to understand where the columns end and contain them */
}
/* ~~ Miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */
.fltrt {  /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* this class can be placed on a <br /> or empty div as the final element following the last floated div (within the .container) if the .footer is removed or taken out of the .container */
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
-->
</style>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="container_8 clearfix">
      <h1 class="grid_1"><img src="resources/img/kite2.png" width="35" height="16"></h1>
      <nav class="grid_5">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li class="fr"><a href="#">administrator<span class="arrow-down"></span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
              <li><a href="index.php">Sign out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <form class="grid_2">
        <input class="full" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
      </form>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sidebar1">
        <div style="padding-top: 5px;">
          <div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
            <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
              <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0" style="border-right: 0px;"><img src="resources/img/tab1.png" alt=""></li>
              <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0"><img src="resources/img/tab2.png"></li>
              <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0"><img src="resources/img/tab3.png"></li>
              <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0"><img src="resources/img/tab4.png"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
              <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Content 1</div>
              <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Content 2</div>
              <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Content 3</div>
              <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Content 4</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="border-left: solid 1px #CCC;"><!-- end .content --></div>
      <div class="content2" style="border-left: solid 1px #CCC;"><!-- end .sidebar2 --></div>
      <!-- end .container --> 
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

i have another attached css file (style.css)

```css
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto!important;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto -50px;
}
footer, #push {
    height:50px;
}
html { height: 100%; }
body {
    font:normal normal normal 11px/16px 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background:#8ec2da;
    height: 100%;
}
.no-border {
    border:none!important;
    -moz-border-radius:0!important;
    -webkit-border-radius:0!important;
    -khtml-border-radius:0!important;
    border-radius:0!important;
}
nav>ul {
    padding:0;
}
a {
    color:#06f;
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
abbr, acronym {
    font-size:85%;
    letter-spacing:.1em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted black;
    cursor:help;
}
abbr[title], acronym[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted #CCC;
    cursor:help;
}
code, kbd, samp, pre, tt, var, .code {
    font-family:Monaco, 'Panic Sans', 'Lucida Console', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-size:20px;
}
h2 {
    font-size:18px;
}
h3 {
    font-size:14px;
}
h4 {
    font-size:13px;
}
h5 {
    font-size:12px;
}
h6 {
    font-size:11px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin:1em 0;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
    color:#000;
}
h4, h5, h6 {
    color:#444;
    font-weight:normal;
}
h6, p {
    color:#676767;
}
h1, h2, h3, b, strong, caption, th, thead, dt, legend {
    font-weight:bold;
}
ul, ol {
    padding-left:2em;
}
li ul, li ol, ul ul, ol ol, dl dd {
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:0;
}
small, sup, sub {
    font-size:90%;
}
.code {
    background-color:#EAEFF4;
    color:#069;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:2px 6px;
}
.al {
    text-align:left!important;
}
.ar {
    text-align:right!important;
}
.ac {
    text-align:center!important;
}
.fl {
    float:left!important;
}
.fr {
    float:right!important;
}
body.login {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.login-box {
    margin:0 auto!important;
    margin-top:-140px!important;
    margin-left:-175px!important;
    position:absolute!important;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:350px;
}
.login-box form {
    border-bottom:1px solid #DDD;
    margin:10px 0;
}
.login-box ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}
.login-box.main-content {
    min-height:0;
}
#promo {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    background:#f9d835;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f9d835), to(#f3961c));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9d835, #f3961c);
    -pie-background:linear-gradient(top, #f9d835, #f3961c);
    padding:10px 0;
}
#promo p {
    color:#fff;
    margin:0;
    line-height:26px;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #000;
}
#promo .close {
    color:#e83;
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:1px 5px;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#wrapper>header {
    background:#434343;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #434343, #191919);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#434343), to(#191919));
    -pie-background:linear-gradient(top, #434343, #191919);
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 1px 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 1px 2px;
    -khtml-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 1px 2px;
    -pie-box-shadow:#bbb -2px 1px 2px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 1px 2px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:999;
    zoom:1;
}
#wrapper>header h1 {
    color:#fff;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:40px;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
}
#wrapper>header h1 a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#wrapper>header nav {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/line_vert.png) repeat-y top left;
}
#wrapper>header nav ul {
    padding:0;
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul {
    padding-left:10px;
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul>li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul>li a {
    color:#eee;
    display:block;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul li:hover>a {
    color:#fff;
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul>li:hover:not(.action)>a {
background:#555;
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #222);
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#555), to(#222));
-pie-background:linear-gradient(top, #555, #222);
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul>li.active>a {
    background:#191919!important;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul>li.action {
    border:1px solid #444;
    border:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    margin-top:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin-right:4px;
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul>li.action>a.button {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:16px;
    padding:4px 10px;
    border:1px solid #111;
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul>li>a span.arrow-down {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/arrows.png) no-repeat 0 -103px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:6px;
    margin-left:8px;
    width:10px;
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul>li:hover>a span.arrow-down {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/arrows.png) no-repeat -10px -103px;
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul ul {
    background:#191919;
    -moz-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
    display:none;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    z-index:999;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 2px #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 2px #777;
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 2px 2px #777;
    box-shadow:0 2px 2px #777;
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul ul li a {
    padding:0 10px;
    line-height:30px;
}
#wrapper>header nav>ul ul li a:hover {
    background:#434343;
}
#wrapper>header form input[type=text] {
    background:#777;
    border:1px solid #191919;
    margin-top:7px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 0 #ddd;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 #ddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 1px 0 #ddd;
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
#wrapper>header form input[type=text]:hover {
    background:#888;
}
#wrapper>header form input[type=text]:focus {
    background:#eee;
}
#wrapper>section {
    padding-top:60px;
}
.has-promo #wrapper>section {
    padding-top:110px;
}
.main-section {
    background:#afd4e6;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    margin-bottom:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    height: 100%;
}
.main-section .content {
    padding:20px 20px 20px 0;
        height: 100%;

}
.main-section .content h3:first-child {
    margin-top:0;
}
.main-content {
    background:#fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px #555;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px #555;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 0 3px #555;
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
.main-content>header {
    background:#eee;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #e1e1e1);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fafafa), to(#e1e1e1));
    -pie-background:linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #e1e1e1);
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    padding:15px 30px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 1px #bbb;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px #bbb;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 1px 1px #bbb;
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -pie-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.main-content>header h2 {
    font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', 'Bitstream Charter', Times, serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:18px;
    margin:0;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
}
.main-content>header h4 {
    margin:0;
}
.main-content>header .avatar {
    background:#fff url(../../resources/img/user_32.png) no-repeat center center;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px #777;
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 0 3px #777;
    box-shadow:0 0 3px #777;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:60px;
    margin-right:10px;
    width:60px;
}
.main-content>header .tags {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/icons/tag_blue.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding-left:20px;
}
.main-content>header .tags a {
    font-size:9px;
}
.main-content>header .view-switcher {
    font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', 'Bitstream Charter', Times, serif;
    font-size:18px;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
    position:relative;
}
.main-content>header .view-switcher>h2>a {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/arrow-updown.png) no-repeat center center;
    display:inline-block;
    text-indent:-999em;
    width:10px;
    height:17px;
}
.main-content>header .view-switcher ul {
    background:#dedeff;
    border:1px solid #999;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 0 3px #888;
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow:0 0 3px #888;
    box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:10px 20px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    margin:-10px -20px;
    top:-12px;
    left:-1px;
    min-width:160px;
}
.main-content>header .view-switcher ul li {
    font-size:12px;
}
.main-content>header .view-switcher ul li.separator {
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
    margin:10px 0;
}
.main-content>header .view-switcher ul li a {
    color:#222;
    display:block;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:40px;
    margin:0 -20px;
    padding:0 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.main-content>header .view-switcher ul li a:hover {
    background:#afd4e6;
}
.main-content>header .action-buttons {
    position:relative;
    top:-4px;
    z-index:999;
}
.main-content>section {
    padding:20px 30px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
}
.main-content>section.container_6 {
    padding:20px;
}
.main-content>section hgroup {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.main-content>section hgroup h2 {
    padding-top:10px;
    margin:0 0 3px 0;
    line-height:1.3em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.main-content>section hgroup h4 {
    line-height:1.4em;
    margin:0 0 30px;
}
.main-content>section .other-options h3 {
    color:#555;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #999;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
.main-content>section .other-options ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}
.main-content>section .other-options h4 {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.main-content>section .other-options h4+p {
    margin-top:0;
}
.list-view {
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-left:-30px;
    margin-right:-30px;
}
.list-view>li {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:10px 30px 10px 55px;
    position:relative;
    zoom:1;
}
.list-view>li.contact {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/icons/vcard.png) no-repeat 30px 10px;
}
.list-view>li.company {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/icons/building.png) no-repeat 30px 10px;
}
.list-view>li.note {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/icons/note.png) no-repeat 30px 10px;
}
.list-view>li.tick {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/icons/tick.png) no-repeat 30px 10px;
}
.list-view>li.calendar {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/icons/calendar.png) no-repeat 30px 10px;
}
.list-view>li:hover {
    background-color:#fafafa;
}
.list-view>li.current {
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
.list-view>li .more {
    background:#bcf url(../../resources/img/arrow-right.png) no-repeat center center;
    display:block;
    width:16px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-indent:-999em;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.list-view>li .more:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.list-view>li:hover .more {
    visibility:visible;
}
.list-view>li.current .more {
    background-image:url(../../resources/img/arrow-left.png);
    visibility:visible;
}
.list-view>li .timestamp {
    color:#555;
    float:right;
    font-size:9px;
}
.list-view>li a {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.list-view>li p {
    color:#111;
    margin:0;
}
.list-view>li .entry-meta {
    color:#555;
}
.list-view>li .avatar {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    float:left;
    height:32px;
    margin-right:4px;
    width:32px;
}
.list-view>li .avatar img {
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
}
.grid-view li {
    background:#fff;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 0 3px #777;
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    box-shadow:0 0 3px #777;
    box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    position:relative;
    width:180px;
}
.grid-view>li .more {
    background:#bcf url(../../resources/img/arrow-right.png) no-repeat center center;
    -moz-border-radius:0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
    -khtml-border-radius:0 3px 3px 0;
    border-radius:0 3px 3px 0;
    display:block;
    width:16px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-indent:-999em;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.grid-view>li .more:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.grid-view>li:hover .more {
    visibility:visible;
}
.grid-view>li.current .more {
    background-image:url(../../resources/img/arrow-left.png);
    visibility:visible;
}
.grid-view li .timestamp {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:15px;
    display:block;
    font-size:9px;
}
.grid-view li .name {
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.grid-view li .entry-meta {
    font-size:9px;
}
.grid-view li .avatar {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    float:left;
    height:60px;
    margin-right:4px;
    width:60px;
}
.grid-view>li .avatar img {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
}
.listing {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}
.listing>li.contact .avatar {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/user_32.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.listing>li.company .avatar {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/users_business_32.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.preview-pane {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
.preview-pane .preview {
    background:#fcfcfc;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    left:-370px;
    padding:20px;
    position:absolute;
    height:350px;
    width:310px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
    border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 2px #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 2px #777;
    -khtml-box-shadow:0 2px 2px #777;
    box-shadow:0 2px 2px #777;
}
.preview-pane .preview>h3:first-child, .preview-pane .preview>h4:first-child {
    margin-top:0;
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav {
    padding:10px 0;
    margin-right:-20px;
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav>ul {
    display:block;
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav>h4 {
    color:#333;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:0;
    padding-left:8px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #eee;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav>ul>li {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav>ul>li a {
    color:#333;
    display:block;
    font-size:11px;
    padding:5px 4px 5px 8px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px #fff;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -moz-border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
    border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
    line-height:16px;
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav>ul>li>a:hover {
    background:#9ecbe0;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav>ul>li.active>a {
    background:#afd4e6;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    color:#111;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav>ul>li a h5, #wrapper>section>div>aside nav>ul>li a h6 {
    line-height:140%;
    margin:0;
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav>ul>li a h5 {
    margin-bottom:3px;
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav>ul>li a h6 {
    font-size:9px;
    text-shadow:none;
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav.global>ul>li>a span {
    background:#def;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -khtml-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    float:right;
    font-size:9px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:0 4px;
    margin-right:2px;
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav.subnav {
    background:transparent url(../../resources/img/line.png) repeat-x top left;
}
#wrapper>section>div>aside nav>ul>li a.nav-icon {
    background-position:5px 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left:25px;
}
.icon-book {
    background-image:url(../../resources/img/icons/book.png)!important;
}
.icon-house {
    background-image:url(../../resources/img/icons/house.png)!important;
}
.icon-note {
    background-image:url(../../resources/img/icons/note.png)!important;
}
.icon-tick {
    background-image:url(../../resources/img/icons/tick.png)!important;
}
.icon-time {
    background-image:url(../../resources/img/icons/time.png)!important;
}
.apple_overlay {
    display:none;
    background-image:url(resources/img/white.png);
    width:640px;
    padding:35px;
    font-size:11px;
}
.apple_overlay .close {
    background-image:url(../../resources/img/close-icon.png);
    position:absolute;
    right:14px;
    top:14px;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
}
.apple_overlay.black {
    background-image:url(../../resources/img/transparent.png);
    color:#fff;
}
```

third css file (reset.css)

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    /*content:none;*/
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted #000;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding overflow: auto; to your elements :)

Comment: thanks but its not working. i've updated the question with other css files i'm using

Answer (score 0):

`div#wrapper` is the first div mentioned in your HTML - and it has no styles applied at all.

Answer (score 0):

100% height will only work if the parent has an absolute height defined. You need to define the height for the parent first and then the child will get 100% of its height.

Comment: how about this? here is an example i got shown: http://jsfiddle.net/wJ73v/ i have different stylesheets and i'm struggling to implement it!